# Lucene/Solr: Book Text Searching

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am trying use the Lucene/Solr for full text searching of documents that are structured like books. The structure of a book looks like:

```
Book
    - has many Chapters
        - has many Lines
```

I can put each line of text as a separate document into the system and text search works fine. The problem I'm running into is that sometimes the query is spread across two lines of text so neither line matches very well and the match isn't made.

Simple Example:

```
It was the best of times.
It was the worst of times.
```

A query for "best worst" wouldn't match either line very well individually but together they would match very well.

Is there a way in Lucene (or better solution) to do this type of structured data searching?

Comment: Is there a reason you are indexing each line as a separate document?

Comment: In the specific application I want the result to show the chapter and line number(s) of matched text.

Comment: Though I'm not convinced with each line as a document, why don't you try each paragraph as a document. It is not that this solution is elegant, but might solve your problem.

Comment: The tool I would look to is [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).  I'm not quite sure what the best way to accomplish this would be, at this point.  I believe you will need to change the nature of your documents to fix this issue, to index paragraphs, chapters, sentences, or something along those lines.  No queries span across documents, to my knowledge.  Incorporating some form of metadata indicating line breaks/numbers might be necessary.  I'll post an answer if I come up with a strategy I'm happy with.